# AWS SQS groups multiple messages at random?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a workflow that ingests/transforms a large CSV, splits it into 20 smaller pieces, and uploads them to `Postgres` using `SQS`/`Lambda`. Essentially, each of the 20 messages in the queue should represent one file. This is causing issues because messages are being grouped together such that one in flight message will try to process multiple messages/files. The `SQS` event basically looks like this:

```json
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "messageId": guid,
      "receiptHandle": hash ,
      "body": file path 1,
    },
    {
      "messageId": guid,
      "receiptHandle": hash ,
      "body": file path 2,
    },
    {
      "messageId": guid,
      "receiptHandle": hash ,
      "body": file path 3,
    }
  ]
}
```

Where it tries to process all three with one lambda invocation. Ideally, I would like 20 invocations of one file like this:

```json
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "messageId": guid,
      "receiptHandle": hash ,
      "body": file path 1,
    },
  ]
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-sqs.html) you should set the `BatchSize` property to `1`.

> BatchSize
> The maximum number of items to retrieve in a single batch.

---

If you are using the **AWS Console**, go on your lambda, click on `Add Trigger` select `SQS` and set the `BatchSize` to `1`:

[image]

---

In **CloudFormation** using **sam** template:

```yaml
YourFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Events:
      SQSEvent:
        Type: SQS
        Properties:
          Queue: YourQueue
          BatchSize: 1
```

Comment: any idea how to do this through the console?